# Restaging of application in Bluemix failed

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, loopbackjs, cloudant

Created a LoopBack application with CloudantDB as data source. Running fine when tested locally. Published the application and product successfully on Bluemix leveraging API designer.

But when I bind CloudantDB service with app on Bluemix and try to re-stage it, getting following error.can anyone help me resolve this issue? Any help in this context will be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
{ code: 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT', connect: false, name: 'Error', message: 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT', stack: 'Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT\n at ClientRequest. (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/request/request.js:778:19)\n at ClientRequest.g (events.js:291:16)\n at emitNone (events.js:86:13)\n at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:185:7)\n at TLSSocket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:620:10)\n at TLSSocket.g (events.js:291:16)\n at emitNone (events.js:86:13)\n at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)\n at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:339:8)\n at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)\n at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)\n at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)' }
```

Comment: The code in question...?

Comment: I've resolved this issue. Thanks..

Comment: Can you post what fixed your issue?

Comment: @SunnyGoel Can you please post an answer that describes how you solved your issue. This will help other users who have the same issue in the future. Thanks

Comment: @SunnyGoel: Can you please post an answer. I'm getting the same error while working with CouchDb service deployed using docker and communicating with socket pouch.

Comment: @AshvinKanani , apologies for delayed response. I hope, you got help from someone to resolve your issue. If not, then here's what i did to resolve my issue. I created a new hostname and used "mybluemix.net" domain to restage and run my loopback app.